# Retriving data from a post web service (with header)

Tags: android, curl, libcurl

I want to fetch data from post web service after setting some parameters in header of that url. I have php code that works fine that sample php code is

```
$headers = array(
    'fname': 'curl',
    'lname': 'header',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Setting a header in android seem to be issue. Sample android code is

```
String [] headers = {
        "fname:curl",
        "lname:header"
};

curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers );
```

Any suggestion how can i set header properly in android.

Comment: So the first snippet is PHP. What is the second one?

Comment: @DanielStenberg Second Android code to set header